# LoadRunner/PC 11.52 and IE11

Tags: performance-testing, internet-explorer-11, loadrunner

Our current production version is PC 11.52 patch1 and our company is going to start IE11 roll out soon. We don't have many issues with our current production version so we would like to use it. But 11.52 doesn't support IE11. Because full migration needs lots of work (we have more than 100 projects), we are investigating alternative solutions. We tested 11.52 Vugen with IE11 and it seems, that Vugen can record scripts in WinInet mode. Would it be possible to record scripts using WinInet level capture and run them using Sockets? Is there some limitations using WinInet capturing and what pitfalls this approach might bring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about PC 11.52 but I can answer regarding LoadRunner 11.52 (VuGen 11.52) It doesn't support IE11 because in IE11 Microsoft added some API which we had to add to the LoadRunner in order for it to work. The API was officially added in version 12 but a patch exists for version 11.52. The problem is that the patch is not available for direct download so you will have to open a support case. When you open the case please describe the problem and ask the patch for defect (77102).

EDIT: If you ask the same question on the official LoadRunner support forum then the support staff will be able to attach the file directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What are your experiences using this patch, does your VuGen work well with IE11?

Comment: I am a developer on the LoadRunner team :)

Comment: Ok :D Thanks again, I'll contact the support.

Comment: @Buzzy I just opened a support thread on the LR customer section asking for this patch.  Glad I found this SO post.  Thanks :)